# MySQL: Find all multiple second level domains

Tags: mysql, regex, group-by

I have a table with thousands offers from different countries. Some offers run on different domains for different countries. For example supershop runs three different domains for three different countries:

supershop.com, supershop.fr & supershop.nl

In my database, the URL entries may look different:

```
http://supershop.com
https://www.supershop.fr/home/index.php
https://supershop.nl
```

Now, how can I SELECT all rows of the same SLD (Second Level Domain) names?

It should be something like

```
SELECT 
    landingpage, 
    COUNT(landingpage)
FROM
    angebote
GROUP BY REGEXP "^(https?://|www\\.)[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"
HAVING COUNT(landingpage) > 1
```

Grouped by this part: `[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]`

Any solutions/hints?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using 10.3.15-MariaDB-1 - Debian 10.

Comment: What about `foo.com` versus `foo.co.uk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/) to extract the second level domain from each URL, and then `GROUP BY` that value:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(landingpage, "^(?:https?://(?:www\\.)?)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(/.*)?$", "\\1") AS sld, 
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM angebote 
GROUP BY sld
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
sld         count
supershop   3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3cde2aa3b8a0ca99ed259af2fe2dd27a)

Note I've made some minor modifications to your regex to make it work with `REGEXP_REPLACE` to extract the second level domain.

Comment: Thx, that's ist! Just add  ```HAVING count > 1``` and it works as expected!